# Angular - How to show modal reject reason in table?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, bootstrap-modal

I have small problem to solve.

I have modal controller rejectIssueModalCtrl.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

function rejectIssueModalCtrl($modalInstance, issue, $rootScope) {
    var self = this;
    self.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };

    self.reject = function ($rootScope) {
        $modalInstance.close(self.reason);
        console.log(self.reason);
    };
    $rootScope.reasono = self.reason;                
}

rejectIssueModalCtrl.$inject = ['$modalInstance', 'issue', '$rootScope'];

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('rejectIssueModalCtrl', rejectIssueModalCtrl);
})();
```

When I click the button I can open this modal and write a reason. I want to show this reject reason in table in other controller.

Here's my code from other controller issueDetailsCtrl.js

```
        $scope.reasonoo = $rootScope.reasono;

    function rejectIssue() {
        var rejectModal = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/App/Issue/rejectIssueModal',
            controller: 'rejectIssueModalCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'rejectModal',
            size: 'lg',
            resolve: {
                issue: self.issueData
            }
        });
        rejectModal.result.then(function (reason) {
            issueSvc
                .rejectIssue(self.issueData.id, reason)
                .then(function (issueStatus) {
                    changeIssueStatus(issueStatus.code);
                    getIssue();
                }, requestFailed);
        });
    };
```

and html code

```
<div>
<span class="right" ng-bind="$root.reasono"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see I tried to use $rootScope. I can console.log the reason but I cant make it to show in this html. Any help?

Comment: did you console log $rootScope.reasono , also can you probably create a plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're missing some context, but I believe this is your problem:

```
self.reject = function ($rootScope) {
    $modalInstance.close(self.reason);
    console.log(self.reason);
};
$rootScope.reasono = self.reason;
```

Assuming `self.reason` is bound to the input in your modal, it won't be defined outside of the `reject` callback - that's the nature of async. You're able to log to console because you're doing so within the callback.

Define `$rootScope.reasono` inside of the callback like so:

```
self.reject = function () {
    $modalInstance.close(self.reason);
    console.log(self.reason);
    $rootScope.reasono = self.reason;  
};
```

**Edited** to show that `$rootScope` should be removed as a named parameter in the `reject` function definition.

Comment: I tried it to but I have error

TypeError: Cannot set property 'reasono' of undefined in this line that you add

Comment: You shouldn't be adding $rootScope as a named parameter in your reject function definition. Remove that and it should work.

Comment: removed this line, now I have something like this
function rejectIssueModalCtrl($modalInstance, issue, $rootScope) {
        var self = this;
        self.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };

        self.reject = function ($rootScope) {
            $modalInstance.close(self.reason);
            console.log(self.reason);
        };               
    }

and still nothing :/

Comment: You still have $rootScope as a parameter in your reject function definition. I think you're trying to pass $rootScope to the reject function? But you're not, you're overwriting it. Your function already has $rootScope defined in in the outer scope. Add the $rootScope.reasono = self.reason line back into your reject function definition and get rid of that param.

Comment: I have another problem. Everything works fine until I refresh page. Then reason dissapear. How to avoid this?

Comment: Right now you're storing it in memory, which wipes at refresh. You need to use some sort of database to persist this - no clue what your use case is, but your simplest option would be local storage, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Using root scope is not recommended. For this reason it is recommended to create a service for intercommuncation with variable to store reject reason, then inject this service for each controller - that way you will be able to read/write reason from different controllers.